# The translation of 被世界遗忘的人

Tags: translation

Can "被世界遗忘的人" be translated as "A person forgotten by the world"?

Is my understanding of 被 correct here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doesn't 被 mean "by"?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/doesnt-%e8%a2%ab-mean-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can, but 人 can mean "person" or "people".

You have to use counting word and classifier (一個 ) to indicate it is a person,  and write "一個被世界遗忘的人" (a person who is forgotten by the world). If you meant "The people who are forgotten by the world" then the sentence would be  "一群被世界遗忘的人"(add counting word and classifier 一群 )or " 被世界遗忘的人們"(use plural marker 們 and write 人們 )

The question of "Does 被 mean by?" had been asked and answered here- [Doesn't 被 mean "by"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/doesnt-%e8%a2%ab-mean-by)

*To check if a similar question had been asked, you can type in key words on the 'Search Q & A' box on the upper right corner of the page.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right.

If we say 人们, then the correct translation should be "people".
But 人 most often means a single person or a human being.

ps:
Can I say "most often"?
I am a Chinese who is learning English.